# How to import SQL database if encoding is unknown

Tags: mysql, sql, encoding

I have a database.sql file and I need to deploy it on my MySQLServer.

So I open the workbench and I open the file and the query appears.
This database has translations in lots of languages and some of them are ruined:

[image]

And some words in Chineese, Urdu, Indian etc show like this:

[image]

[image]

I'm not used to encodings but I don't know how to import it to restore that data to the original charset. Thank you un advance.

Comment: Why do you think that any of your data is ruined? Chinese and Urdu do not use the latin alphabet, so their characters would appear funny when displayed in a latin environment, such as your screen.The encoding is known: utf8mb4, which is the true utf8 encoding within MySQL. This encoding's purpose is that you do not have to use different encoding for every language.

Comment: @Shadow So, what I'm supposed to do? Check the same data in another pc with another language on it?

Comment: There could be a number of reasons why your data looks incorrect in your application. utf8mb4 encoding can handle all the alphabets you listed, If the data does not display incorrectly in your application, then either the data is corrupted, or you made a mistake in the code that retrieves and displays the data. There is no way of telling on our side. You have to do some debugging to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's Mojibake.  Without knowing the steps that the data went through, I cannot diagnose it completely.  Several things needed to say utf8mb4 (or at least utf8).  See this for what to check on and 'best practice':  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)